# Stop For Each Loop

Tags: vba, excel

How do you stop a loop after it has ran in Excel? Not sure if I'm describing it properly but in Excel, I've written some code with `For` loop that loops through a range. This range in question has 10382 rows. Anyways, I also have a `MsgBox` line of code.

I realized after running it that it was the wrong place to put the `MsgBox` code. Now I find myself having to click OK on the MsgBox 10382 times. How do I stop it without having to forcefully close Excel.

I've tried clicking the stop button in the VBA editor but it won't let me.

```
For Each cell in rng.Cells
   If Me.txtBox.Value = "" Then
      MsgBox "Enter a Value"
   Else
      'Do Something
   End If
Next
```

Comment: You can use Ctrl+Break

Comment: @tigeravatar thank you.

Comment: @tigeravatar Make that an answer.

Comment: @tigeravatar good answer. I did not even knew that key existed until today.

Answer (score 3):

As tigeravatar already suggested, Ctrl+Break is a good way to stop execution.

However, end users rarely know to do that. A more friendly alternative is to use the MsgBox to ask the question:

```
If MsgBox("Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo Or vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit For
```

- other options are vbOKCancel and vbAbortRetryIgnore